# A sufficient condition for norm equivalence

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Proof:

For any $\left \{ x_k \right \}  \subset X $
if $\left \{ x_k \right \}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(X,\left \| · \right \| _1)$
$\Rightarrow$ $\left \{ x_k \right \}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(X,\left \| · \right \| _2)$

and

$\left \{ x_k \right \}$ isnot a Cauchy sequence in $(X,\left \| · \right \| _1)$
$\Rightarrow$ $\left \{ x_k \right \}$ isnot a Cauchy sequence in $(X,\left \| · \right \| _2)$,

then $\left \| · \right \| _1$  and $\left \| · \right \| _2$ are equivalent.

I tried to prove that $f:(X\setminus \left \{ 0 \right \} ,\left \| · \right \|_1 )\mapsto (X\setminus \left \{ 0 \right \},\left \| · \right \|_2 )=\frac{x}{\left \| x \right \|_1}$ has bound but fail.

Comment: $(P\implies Q) \cong (\sim Q\implies \sim P) $

Comment: Please show your effort.

Comment: Show your thoughts.

Comment: $\|•\|_1\cong\|•\|_2$ iff $Id:(X, \|•\|_1)\to(X,\|•\|_2)$ is bi-lipschitz. [Alternative](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1927758/977780).